# How to get scroll Position in reactjs when click on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrolltop, scroll-position

As you can see it I am not able to scroll down the page when I click on the button, This all code running in one file in App.js

Even I tried with useRef() and UseState() also but not working

I need help in JavaScript logic only

**Javascript:**

```
const myFunction = () => {
        const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        element.scrollLeft = 50;
        element.scrollTop = 10;
    };
```

**HTML:**

```
<div
    id="myDiv"
    style={{ height: "250px", width: "250px", overflow: "auto" }}
>
        <div
                id="content"
                style={{
                height: "800px",
                width: "2000px",
                backgroundColor: "coral",
            }}
        >
        <button onClick={myFunction}>Scroll</button>
        <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
        <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
        <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
        <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```js
const element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
```

the ID is wrong. It should be `myDiv` because you set the div's ID to `myDiv`:

```js
<div
    id="myDiv"
    style={{ height: "250px", width: "250px", overflow: "auto" }}
>
```

and also you can use the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) function of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) instead of setting `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop`:

```js
const myFunction = () => {
  const element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  element.scroll(50, 10);
}
```

But I recommend using refs (I know you mentioned it but I'm not sure if you used it correctly).

Create a ref:

```js
const divRef = useRef();
```

Assign the ref to the div:

```js
<div
    id="myDiv"
    ref={divRef}
    style={{ height: "250px", width: "250px", overflow: "auto" }}
>
```

Then scroll it (you don't need the element variable anymore):

```js
const myFunction = () => {
  divRef.current.scroll(50, 10);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution, but here useRef() getting undefine, will you please help me in that

Comment: @Amit Is there an error?

Comment: I am not getting any error there I am getting undefined value when I look in console log, in comment below I update all my code

Comment: @Amit Ok. I saw your code in codesandbox. You passed `divRef` to the wrong div. Instead pass it to the div that has the `myDiv` ID.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-rgb-hn798p?file=/src/App.js:287-293 ---- ok now I got it working now, and do you know if I remove height and weight size from ref={myDiv} then it is not working, in that case how we handle scroll?? except window.scroll , scrollTo, scrollTop

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"?

Comment: I got my solution. The Issue in CSS, I need to see both both logic together in react and CSS. thanks for the help.

Comment: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228747/reactjs-window-scrollto-not-working-on-secondary-scroll-bar) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174863/javascript-scrollto-method-does-nothing/18573599#18573599) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859550/react-window-scroll-to-bottom)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted.
Since the "scroll" button dissapears after the scroll you can

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setScrollPos(scrollPos + 100);
}, []);

function myFunction() {
// Get the scrollable element which is the parent div.
  let element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  // Set this to whatever you need. Right now it will start at      100, then go to 200, 300...
  setScrollPos(scrollPos + 100);

  // Calls the scroll function.
  element.scroll({
    // Top is for the y position.
    top: scrollPos,
    //Use left for x position.
    //left: 100
    // It looks nicer if the scroll is smooth
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}

return (
<>
  <div
    id="myDiv"
    style={{ height: "250px", width: "250px", overflow: "auto" }}
  >
    <div
      id="content"
      style={{
        height: "800px",
        width: "2000px",
        backgroundColor: "coral"
      }}
    >
      <button
        onClick={myFunction}
        //Add this is you want the button to stay in the corner.
        //style={{ position: "absolute" }}
      >
        Scroll
      </button>
      <br />
      <input onClick={myFunction} type="radio" name="s" id="s" />
      <label onClick={myFunction} htmlFor="">
        Salary Person
      </label>
      <br />
      <input onClick={myFunction} type="radio" name="s" id="s" />
      <label onClick={myFunction} htmlFor="">
        Salary Person
      </label>
      <br />
      <input onClick={myFunction} type="radio" name="s" id="s" />
      <label onClick={myFunction} htmlFor="">
        Salary Person
      </label>
      <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
      <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
      <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
      <p>Some text inside a div element.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
```

);
}

export default App;

Comment: with the help of element its working fine but I need solution in useRef() or UseState() now how will scroll screen with useRef or useState

Comment: @Amit Is this closer to what you were wanting?